# Unlock with a product key not shown on VS2019

Tags: visual-studio

I want to activate VS2019 with license code but I cant see "Unlock with a product key" in "File > Account Settings"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot shows that you are using an ***expired*** **Prerelease** ***version***, and need to upgrade it before you can continue.
*(The option 'Check for an updated license' probably will never work in this scenario, unless MS decides that the old Prerelease is suddenly no longer expired after all)*

You can install the [latest Prerelease version](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/) which you should then be able to license again - or you can install a [regular Release version](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/).

Comment: i hope it work, i'm in downloading latest Prerelease version

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Help] -> [Register Product]

Comment: I Can't click anywhere in the VS2019 :(

Answer (score 0):

I repaired VS19, and the option 'Unlock with a Product Key' was returned. But, before having that problem, I deleted the key from the registry)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30989158)